# How to create a list of objects in Typescript in one line

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

I have a list of values

```
let values = ["value-01", "value-02"]
```

I go ahead and turn them into the list of objects:

```
let result = [];
for (let each of values) { 
  result.push({ value: each });    
};

console.log(result)
```

which logs

```
[ { value: 'value-01' }, { value: 'value-02' } ]
```

I wonder if there is a shorter way to achieve this? In Python I could do it in a single line like so:

```
result = [{"value": each} for each in values]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pretty simple mapping.

```js
let values = ["value-01", "value-02"];
const result = values.map(value => ({ value }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I haven't seen that syntax before. Would that be creating an array of objects, each with a field called 'result'?

Comment: Yes, you can press "Run code snippet" to see. `({ result })` results in an object with one property, named `result`, whose value is the same as the value currently in the `result` identifier.

Comment: This produces `[ { result: 'value-01' }, { result: 'value-02' } ]` instead of `[ { value: 'value-01' }, { value: 'value-02' } ]`

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing wrong with using a for loop, you could make use of this code using `map()`, `split()` and computed property names:

```js
let values = ["value-01", "value-02"];
let ans = values.map((a) => ({ [a.split('-')[0]] : a }))  
console.log(ans);
```